# Stop the Opening of the application from the lock screen

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, notifications

How to stop opening up the certain application from the lock screen when the notification came

For E.G: I got the local notification from the app, when my phone was locked then I was opened the lock its automatically opening the app how do I stop it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot stop this behaviour, it's embedded into ios. If you put your device to sleep after a notification then the slide will return to slide to unlock. With the notifications showing only at the top.